# Can Protected Custom Settings be CRUD'ed via the REST API? (Created, Read, Updated, and Deleted)

Tags: apex, rest-api, customsetting

Can a protected custom setting be created, read, updated, and deleted from the REST API? Is it the same REST API that is used for SObjects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely execute CRUD via the REST API for a Protected Custom Setting - but I ended up writing a custom REST class that receives some JSON, checks for an existing record in the C/S, and then executes the create/update.

kwzdso_*ZDMoAuthSettings*_c is my custom setting in the package:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/zdmsettings')
global class KWD_aSyncSettings {

     @HttpPost
     global static void setAPITokens() {

        String sResponse = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
        Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(sResponse);     

        Map<String, kwzdso__ZDMoAuthSettings__c> zdmoauth =  kwzdso__ZDMoAuthSettings__c.getall();

        kwzdso__ZDMoAuthSettings__c zdmnew;
        if (zdmoauth.size()  == 0) {//Empty
            zdmnew = new kwzdso__ZDMoAuthSettings__c();
            zdmnew.Name = 'ZDM';
            zdmnew.kwzdso__Endpoint__c = (String)m.get('instance_url');
            zdmnew.kwzdso__Refresh_Token__c = (String)m.get('refresh_token');
        }
        else {
            zdmnew = zdmoauth.get('ZDM');
            zdmnew.kwzdso__Endpoint__c = (String)m.get('instance_url');
            zdmnew.kwzdso__Refresh_Token__c = (String)m.get('refresh_token');
       }

        upsert zdmnew;

        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('ok');

     }
}
```

Comment: Is this a protected custom setting from a managed package, as i am pretty sure the platform should prevent these from being seen by Apex outside of the package?

Comment: @AndrewFawcett You're right. That's why there's the custom rest service. Without it, the settings are not accessible outside whatever UI the managed package presents to the user.

Comment: Correct - the package in question is setup as a site wide licence - and then we use a ConnectedApp to generate an oauth token. What I haven't tested is if a user without access to the package can post to the rest service = I assume no, but you never know with these things...